# Secure frontend to backend call, sensitive information

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, security, post

I don't have a direct problem, but rather a question.
I have a React frontend and a Spring Boot backend.
Authentication is done by JWT.
The project contains a virtual wallet where the user can deposit money.
To deposit money I create a "Deposit" on the backend page once the user specifies how much he wants to deposit in the frontend (step 1).
This deposit contains the following information:

- Purpose Key (To recognize the transfer).
- Amount
- Payment method (Paypal, bank transfer)
- Timestamp
- Status (Open, Canceled, Paid)
- User

A user can have an infinite number of deposits, a deposit can have only one user.
As soon as the user has deposited the money (step 3) (with Paypal this happens immediately) the deposit status is updated and the money is credited to the user.
However, this mechanism can be easily manipulated by an attacker using a POST request to create deposits and then updating them to "PAID".

I can't think of a way to solve this problem. That is the reason for this question.

To summarize everything again:
User opens "cash in" -> amount is selected -> request to backend generates a deposit and responds with a purposeKey -> user selects bank transfer OR paypal ->.
Paypal: payment window opens, amount is credited immediately if successful
Bank transfer: purpose key and bank details are displayed to the user

Comment: The attacker should not have access to your backend without a token if you are authenticating with jwt. They would need a valid token to have access. So what do you mean by the mechanism would be easily manipulated with a POST request? They shouldn't be able to make one.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but he just would need to open the networks tab, copy the auth header and fire a new post request with modified data?

Comment: Paypal gives you a transaction number for you to reference it with when the transaction is complete don't they? You  should send that to the backend and then verify on the backend. You should never give the frontend the ability to mark things as paid.